# How to sort forum's users by "total_content_length" and then by most recent post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, active-relation

I would like to sort forum's users by `total_content_length`. To get the top `n` writers in the forum I do:

```
User.order("total_content_length DESC").limit(n)
```

Now, the problem is when there are two (or more) users with the same `total_content_length`.
In this case, I would like to give preference to the user that created a post most recently.

`Post` has `publisher_id` field (which is a user `id`).

How would you do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use 2 order statements:

```
User.order("total_content_length DESC").order("created_at DESC").limit(n)
```

Try this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :your_scope_name, joins(:posts).order("posts.created_at DESC")
end
```

then you can use this `scope` in conjunction with other statements

Comment: User's `created_at` is not relevant here. It should be related somehow to `Post`'s `created_at`.

Comment: so you can create some scope for User where you will find his posts and order them by created_at, then you can replace .order("created_at DESC") with your new scope

Comment: How would you write this scope for user?

Comment: you can use joins in the scope

Comment: @bor1s: I will appreciate a more detailed answer :)

Comment: I'he edited my post, take a look, I hope it will help you, also if you see that it is not quite correct you can modify it as you wish

Comment: Thanks, but it's not really helpful :( When you use `joins` the result set is usually bigger. For example, if there are 3 users, and each user has 2 posts, `joins` will return 6 entries, rather than 3.

Comment: use uniq for resulted collection to avoid duplicating records

Answer (score 0):

Define a method in your User model that gives the date of the latest post (assuming you have a posts association):

```
def date_of_last_post  
  posts.order('created_at DESC').limit(1)[0].created_at  
end
```

Then you can get the result as:

```
top_posters = User.order("total_content_length DESC").limit(n)
# write a conditional sorting algo that swaps values only 
# if a.total_content_length == b.total_content_length based on 'date_of_last_post'
```

Comment: That's not right, because when you do the `sort!` you "forget" about the previous `order` sort...

Comment: Edited my answer. It is not the best approach, but can get you going for the time being. You can use any standard sorting algo.